# Is it permissible to insult on the basis of nationality?

Tags: support, code-of-conduct

Is the following phrase allowed to be used on gis.stackexchange.com?

> F-word you all `nationality` bast**ds.

or does it violate the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)?

> **No bigotry.**
> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or
> alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion
> — and those are just a few examples. Use stated pronouns (when known).
> When in doubt, don't use language that might offend or alienate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention.  We take all reports of any conduct on our site which falls outside our code seriously.

If that phrase appears in a question, answer, comment or chat, and it was first-time misconduct for a user I would remove it, and send the user a warning.

If it appears in a profile, then I personally think that my action should be the same. However, I'm mindful that many Stack Exchange users believe that they are able to write whatever they like in their own profile, and so I sought peer review from other moderators before deciding whether to proceed with that action.

I have sought that peer review, and [this advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231362/215590), in answer to [Is it acceptable to insult god in a user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231334/is-it-acceptable-to-insult-god-in-a-user-profile), has guided me to remove that phrase from the GIS SE user profile in which I observed it.

This answer will serve as the warning that the phrase must not be returned to the user's profile.